# How force the database to use function based index in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Here is the code, and I'm trying to create a function based index.

But Oracle did not apply it when computing the query results.

Things works fine when I'm not using two tables

Comment: Its optimizer's choice to use Index if it helps to improve performance.

Comment: There is no real benefit of the index as far as the optimizer is concerned. You should add the columns `SERVEDBY`and `AMOUNT` to the index and then only select required columns in the subquery.

Comment: why are you using a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `INDEX` hint:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
  FROM (SELECT /*+ INDEX(P SERVICE_INDEX) */
               P.*, E.* 
          FROM PURCHASE P
          INNER JOIN EMP E
            ON E.EMPNO = P.SERVEDBY
          WHERE INSTR(P.SERVICETYPE, 'Software') = 0) 
  WHERE DEPTNO = 50
```

Note that there may be very good reasons for the optimizer to ignore your index.